# play sound effect clicking on a link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, click

I want to fire mouseclick sound effect on each click on page.

```
<audio id='aclick'>
  <source src="audio/click.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

$(document).on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("aclick").play();
});
```

generally it works but it doesn't work on `link` element.

Clicking on any `<a></a>` element - there is no sound.

example of my link:

`<a href='index.php'><img id='logoc' src='img/02.jpg' alt='img'></a>`

Comment: please share html of link element

Comment: @brk, I  did - pls see

Comment: there is no audio source in the anchor tag

Comment: @brk, but anchor tag is part of `$(document)`, isnt it ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach the event handler to any tags which have click events like below

```
$("*").on('click',function(){
  document.getElementById("aclick").play();
});
```

And audio tag like below

```
<audio id='aclick' autoPlay='false' preLoad='auto' >
  <source src="audio/click.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio
```

Comment: but I don't need to play the sound only by clicking on a link. I want to play it by clicking on any element on page.

Comment: Used * selector

Comment: simpy nothing. I think problem is with redirecting which starts immediately after clicking on a link and sound has no time to play. But this is a small audio file, about 9KB, it should be played anyway.

Comment: OK then you need to use event.preventDefault() to stop the default action of link and then play the sound and then use  `window.location.href ` to redirect to the actual link

Comment: with preloading it plays on a page load, and still not on a link tag clicking.